# How to create binaries for virtual machines?

Tags: java, c++, jvm, vm-implementation

Recently I have been extremely interested in language development, I've got multiple working front ends and have had various systems for executing the code. I've decided I would like to try to develop a virtual machines type system. (Kind of like the JVM but much simpler of course) So I've managed to create a basic working instruction set with a stack and registers but I'm just curious about how some things should be implemented.

In Java for example after you've written a program you compile it with the java compiler and it creates a binary (.class) for the JVM to execute. I don't understand how this is done, how does the JVM interpret this binary, what's the transition from human readable instructions to this binary, how could I create something similar?

Thanks for any help/suggestions!

Comment: Compiling to bytecode is essentially no different to compiling to native machine code, so I suggest reading a good book on compilers.

Comment: Dragon Book by Aho and Ullman, perhaps, or is that now hopelessly out of date?

Comment: Dragon Book is the most generic response there can possibly be on anything regarding language development, doesn't make me to happy when I see it. Also I do believe it's quite out of date.

Comment: @john: Aho/Uhlmann will never be out of date :) IMHO...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Hmm... I imagined it would be quite different but I will look into it.

Comment: @APott: It's not out of date in the sense that compilers still follow the same basic steps as they always have.  (In any case, the 2nd Edition was published in 2006...)

Comment: So you're saying the Dragon Book provides instructions to how to compile byte code/machine code? I don't understand everything I find online even remotely related to developing languages someone always mentions the dragon book, it can't include everything. I understand the steps to the compiler and the theory, this is not my question.

Comment: @APott: It sure sounds like it's your question.  If "how do I translate from human readable instructions to binary" is not your question, maybe you should remove it from your post.  If that _is_ the question, then you clearly don't understand the steps to the compiler.

Comment: @APott: It tells you how a compiler works, including code generation, optimization, garbage collection, etc. which is what you need to know.

Comment: In my last comment I was asking if the Dragon Book actually covers everything I hear people recommending it for since it's constantly recommended.

Comment: @APott I feel it's still unclear what you actually want to know?  You say in your question that you have working front ends, a instruction set spec and a basic machine for that instruction set. It sounds like you're asking about how to implement code generation for a VM instruction set (which, as others have said, is not very different from code generation for x86, say).

Comment: Yes that's what I'm asking, I just find it hard to believe bytecode generation is similar to x86 code generation...

Comment: @APott: They're both just instruction sets; why would the concepts be massively different?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I just thought it would be different because x86 code is for physical hardware and byte code would be for a piece of software.

Comment: @APott But the 'piece of software' essentially has to do the same thing as the physical hardware. You have to have an `add` instruction in your VM bytecode just like in x86. You have to have load/stores, jumps, et cetera. *Especially* if your aim is to start with a *simple* VM, you will end up with something that looks like a very light version of x86 bytecode.

Comment: @us2012 Just to be sure I'm using the correct terms--byte code would be the compiled/assembled binary correct? I understand these instructions need to be implemented but the issue is right now I'm just directly interpreting them from the human readable form. My question is how to get to the byte code/binary representation. That does make sense though.

Comment: @APott: If you "understand the steps to the compiler and the theory" you know exactly how to go from a human-readable programming language to (byte-)code. If not, you have gotten ahead of yourself and need to write a simple compiler.

Comment: @GManNickG To "understand the steps to the compiler and theory" literally means the stages and theory to a compiler... I never said I knew how to generate machine code, but after the information I gathered here from some helpful comments I suppose that's what I need to do.

Comment: @APott: Here's a summary:  If the user wants to add, save the op-code that represents "add" to the output file.

Comment: @APott: Sounds like you're maybe mixing up parser with compiler. A compiler generates *something*, and I'm having a hard time figuring out what your output was if not some form of code. If you evaluated the AST or IR directly, your output for the VM is whatever instructions are needed to model that evaluation.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone, I have a good start now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I'll bite on this generic question.

Implementing an compiler/assembler/vm combo is a tall order, especially if you're doing it by yourself.
That being said: If you keep your language specification simple enough, it is quite doable; also by yourself.

Basically, to create a binary, the following is done (this is a *tad* bit simplified*:

1) Input source is read, lexed, and tokenized

2) The program logic is analyzed for semantical correctness.

E.g. while the following C++ would parse & tokenize, it would fail semantic analysis

```
float int* double = const (_identifier >><<) operator& *
```

3) Build an Abstract Syntax Tree to represent the statements

4) Build symbol tables and resolve identifiers

5) *Optional*: Optimization of code

6) Generate code in an output format of your choice; for example binary opcodes/operands, string tables. Whatever format suits your needs best. Alternatively, you could create bytecode for an existing VM, or for a native CPU.

**EDIT**
If you want to devise your own bytecode format, you can write, for example:

```
1) File Header
DWORD filesize
DWORD checksum
BYTE  endianness;
DWORD entrypoint <-- Entry point for first instruction in main() or whatever
2) String table
DWORD numstrings
<strings>
DWORD stringlen
<string bytes/words>

3) Instructions
DWORD numinstructions
<instructions>
DWORD opcode
DWORD numops <--- or deduce from opcode
DWORD op1_type <--- stack index, integer literal, index to string table, etc
DWORD operand1
DWORD op1_type
DWORD operand2
...
```

**END**

Overall, the steps are managable, but, as always, the devil is in the details.

Some good references are:

[The Dragon Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321486811) - This is heavy on theory, so it's a dry read, but worthwhile

[Game Scripting Mastery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1931841578) - Guides you along while developing all three components in a more practical matter. However, the example code is rife with security issues, memory leaks, and overall lousy coding style (imho). However, you can take a lot of concepts away from this book, and it's worth a read.

[The Art of Compiler Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130481904) - I have not read this one personally, but heard positive things about it.

**If you decide to go down this road, be sure you know what you're getting yourself into. This is not something some the faint of heart, or someone new to programming. It requires *a lot* of conceptual thinking and prior planning. It is, however, quite rewarding and fun**

Comment: I hear the same old things every time, I understand these stages and have completed all but the last, I can't believe the only solution is to purchase a book just to figure out how to create a binary format for my instruction set. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: You asked "what's the transition from human readable instructions to this binary". This is how it can be done. If you already have symbol tables, string tables, did the operand resolution, know stack offsets for locals & globals, etc, then you can design a simple file format that is written to by the assembler and read by the VM and then executed. What are you asking for, then, exactly? How to write a binary file?

Comment: @APott: are you wondering about the translation step (from an AST into a list of bytecode tokens), or are you wondering about code generation  step (from bytecode tokens to a file)?

Comment: Byte code tokens to a file, that area is just extremely fuzzy, I can't find any information on it. Thanks for all the responses thus far!

Comment: Ok, check my edit; maybe that gives you a starting point on what such a file might look like

Comment: Oh yes! Thank you very, very, very much! That gives me a very good idea on what to do, thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. The actual layout will of course depend on your data and what you need/want to support.

Answer (score 1):

@APott -

1) Virtual machines don't create binaries.  The Java compiler creates binary .class files; a running JVM loads and executes class files.

2) There's nothing particularly "new" or unique about the Java JVM.  Conceptually, it's not dissimilar to UCSD Pascal or IBM MV/370.  Here's a good short history of VM's:

- http://cap-lore.com/Software/CP.html

3) If you're interested, the complete JVM specification is on-line, and there are many books/links that discuss it in detail:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/
- http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/jvmP.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine

Comment: With the first question, I guess that's what I meant by that, my question is a combination of how the binaries are created and interpreted by the VM. I was only using the JVM as an example since it's a quite known system. Still history doesn't exactly help with my question here. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: There are many different kinds of "executable binaries", and many different ways that an "environment" can "load and execute" them.  At one end of the spectrum are "interpreters": scripting languages like Perl or Bash.  At the other end, "compiled" languages translate source into machine code, and the OS loads and executes the resulting images.  Java is somewhere in between: Java source is compiled into machine-independent "byte code", which is loaded and executed by the JVM.  The Dragon book discusses all these options in detail.  Also look at the three JVM links I cited.  'Hope that helps...

Comment: Oh updated links, I will read through some things.

Comment: Those links were very helpful, I'm still reading through them but they're giving me some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

All that a compiler does is transform a string to a string, whether the target is a real machine or a virtual machine. Since you're building your own target VM, you might use different way to encode than existing virtual or physical machines instructions sets, but that doesn't really change. All physical machine instruction set can be emulated in software, and all virtual machine instruction set can be run in hardware (though this could be slightly harder in practice since instruction set designed for virtual machine can be much more complex than the hardware budget allows). The CPU, after all, is just an interpreter of an instructions set.

Any compiler books should expand on this, but compilation process is the same for physical or virtual machine. In general, you need to start with **parsing** your source language into a source code abstract syntax tree (AST), then you need a **translation** that transform this source AST into target AST (though the target language are generally much flatter than the source language, so you might not actually need a tree but an array is usually sufficient), then you need **code generation** to transform the target AST into bytecode (this is usually just one to one translation from the target AST node to bytecode). For languages with complicated syntaxes, you may need to have intermediate parsing stages to form concrete syntax trees a.k.a. parse tree before you can form the source AST; and some compilers may use multiple translation stages, and may include an optimizing translator in between; those are minor differences.